# Что означают графики после обучения YOLO?

Tags: машинное-обучение, графики, машинное-зрение

После обучения модели YOLOv8 в папке с весами и в val появились графики F1_curve, P_curve, PR_curve, R_curve. Что означают эти кривые и какие там должны быть результаты, если обучение прошло нормально? Я нашёл описание на сайте ultralytics/yolo-performance-metrics/ но там они особо не раскрываются, все равно не понятно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]